# limit jenkins access to users in a specific ldap group?

Tags: jenkins

I set up Jenkins to allow all users in our OU to login. I now wish to limit access to only those users who are in a particular group. How do I do that? I am able to restrict the "Group search base", but I don't think that limits who can login. I think that just makes the lookup more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

We use the "Matrix Authorization Strategy" plugin to specify which groups have which permissions. https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth

It looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: Does that match against the ldap groups or /etc/group?

Comment: I believe it matches the LDAP groups.